# Diplay multiple chart js Diagrams on one page

Tags: python, html, csv, chart.js

My code is supposed to read out date from three csv Sheets. Next, I want to display the read values with chartjs  in a html file. But the created html file shows the charts overlayed and the titles not at all. Is someone able to tell me the mistake?
Thanks for your help!

head:

```
   window.onload = function () {
   var chartGarage = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainerGarage",
   {
        axisX:{      
            valueFormatString: "H:m" ,
            labelAngle: -50
        },
        axisY:{
            minimum: 40,
            maximum: 95
        },
        data:[
        {
            type: "line",
            dataPoints: [   
    ''') 

r = 0
for row in csvDataGarage:
    if r < 30:
        html.write('{ x: new Date('+ row[0] + '), y:' + row[2] + '},')
    r += 1

html.write('''
                        ]
        }
            ]
    });
    chartGarage.render();
    var chartWerkstatt = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainerWerkstatt",
   {
        axisX:{      
            valueFormatString: "H:m" ,
            labelAngle: -50
        },
        axisY:{
            minimum: 40,
            maximum: 95
        },
        data:[
        {
            type: "line",
            dataPoints: [   
    ''') 

r = 0
for row in csvDataWerkstatt:
    if r < 30:
        html.write('{ x: new Date('+ row[0] + '), y:' + row[2] + '},')
    r += 1

html.write('''
                        ]
        }
            ]
    });
    chartWerkstatt.render();
    var chartWaschhalle = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainerWaschhalle",
   {
        axisX:{      
            valueFormatString: "H:m" ,
            labelAngle: -50
        },
        axisY:{
            minimum: 40,
            maximum: 95
        },
        data:[
        {
            type: "line",
            dataPoints: [   
    ''') 

r = 0
for row in csvDataWaschhalle:
    if r < 30:
        html.write('{ x: new Date('+ row[0] + '), y:' + row[2] + '},')
    r += 1

html.write('''
                        ]
        }
            ]
    });
    chartWaschhalle.render();
    }
</script>
```

body:

```
<section>
    <div class="section-contentGarage">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center"  id="headerTextGarage">
                <h1>Luftfeuchtigkeit</h1>
                <h3>Garage</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="chartContainerGarage"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="section-contentWerkstatt">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center"  id="headerTextWerkstatt">
                <h3>Werkstatt</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="chartContainerWerkstatt"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="section-contentWaschhalle">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center"  id="headerTextWaschhalle">
                 <h3>Garage</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="chartContainerWaschhalle"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>



 <footer>
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-4">
            Rindfleisch Reisen <br>
            Zeughausgasse 3, 6020 Innsbruck<br>
                info@rindfleisch.reisen<br>
                +43512585966
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img class="img-responsive img-centered" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">

                Gewerberechtliche Geschäftsführung: Franz Rindfleisch<br>
                Handelsrechtliche Geschäftsführung: Franz Rindfleisch<br>
                Firmenbuchnummer: 141843<br>
                Firmenbuchgericht: Landesgericht Innsbruck<br>
                UID Nr.: ATU40307707<br>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</footer>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/calibration.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/statusanzeige.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/logfile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/temperatur.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/luftfeuchtigkeit.js"></script>
```

Could someone tell me what I should change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chart.js uses the HTML5 `<canvas>` element to contain the charts - as in the line.html sample:

```
<body>
<div style="width:75%;">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

I don't see a `<canvas>` element in your `<body>` code.
That element is then used in the JavaScript to create the chart element:

```
    window.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
};
```